# Nested <span> inside a <p> tag giving different font size

Tags: html, css

Applying an enlarged font-size using `em` directly to a `<p>` tag and to the nested `<span>` tag are giving different results.

```
body {
 font-size: 14px;
}

p {
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.enlarge {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

<p>Normal paragraph text</p>

<p class="enlarge">Enlarged text</p>

<p><span class="enlarge">This text comes out larger than the above.</span></p>
```

I was expecting both `<p class="enlarge">` and `<p><span class="enlarge">` to give me the same result.

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/huymo47b/

Comment: It will work with `rem` but not with `em`, because `rem` is relative to the `body` while `em` inherit the size based on the parent elements

Comment: if font size is 14px, and p is 1.4em, then p will be 1.4 x 14px (~19.6px). If p is 19.6px, and .enlarge is 1.7em, then .enlarge will be 19.6 x 1.7 (~33.32px)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `rem` (root em) instead of `em`

`em` is relative to the parent element, while `rem` takes reference from the root (html) value

The css code becomes

```
body {
 font-size: 14px;
}

p {
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.enlarge {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}
```

The code can be tested here: https://jsfiddle.net/zrzahoro/

**Update:**

The `rem` takes reference from root, which it html tag. If you want to control the value of font being referenced in your css instead of letting it use the browser default value, give a fixed font-size to `html` tag too.

Comment: Thanks. When I add `html` to the CSS, the font size reduces slightly. Do you know why this is happening? Compare your fiddle with this one: https://jsfiddle.net/zrzahoro/1/

Comment: @user1448031 it's because you're giving "html" (root element which our rem will refer to) a 14px font size too, instead of using your browser default

Answer (score 5):

> "The em unit is a relative unit based on the computed value of the font size of the parent element. This means that child elements are always dependent on their parent to set their font-size."

Reference: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/#article-header-id-3)

Your `<p>` tag has already 1,4 of normal size and `<span class="enlarge">` is 1,7 of its parent (which is already enlarged).