# Font size - percentage mess - and workarounds

Tags: html, css, font-size

I figured it out that `span` not only will inherit `div`'s `font-size`, but also will consider from now on 50% as 100%. So, basically following example won't be the same as 100% for the `span`, because 100% now is: 16`(100%)`-8`(50%)`+4`(50% of 50%)`= 12px`(150% for <span>)`. So it needed to be 200% to be the same.

My question is: what can be done with that, if I want to use `%`. Is there any workarounds(something like CSS reset - it's different, I know)? If not, what is the best alternative for making it more simple for development, but yet effective with responsiveness styling?

**CSS:**

```
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}
div {
  font-size: 50%;
}
div > p > span {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  P P P
  <p>
    <span>
      SPAN
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to explicitly set the font sizes, and do it in `em` rather than in `px` to keep the responsiveness.

Comment: @SimpleBeat Yes, thanks, I'm aware of `em`, but the result will be the same. `em` acts exactly the same, pal... that's the problem

Comment: Maybe `rem` would help then. You first set the default font size for `body` in `em` (for example, `14em`). Then you define other font sizes in `rem` (which stands for *root em*, calculated relative to the top-most font-size, not just the immediate parent). [Here's a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883489/nested-span-inside-a-p-tag-giving-different-font-size?noredirect=1&lq=1)